# jQuery AJAX form error. Empty string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having a problem when I submit a contact form via Ajax to a PHP script. I have used the jQuery/Ajax function previously as well as the contact script, however on this occaison the process runs as far as the ajax request and then returns the error: empty string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#sendmail").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var text = $("#message").val(); 

        //var datastr ='name=' + name + '&mail=' + mail + '&subject=' + subject + '&text=' + text;
        var datastr ='name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;
        $("#form-div").css("float", "left");
        $("#form-div").html("<p>Thank you for contacting Stillframe Photography.</p><p>Please wait for just a few moments while your enquiry is being sent.</p>");
        $("#form-div").fadeIn("slow");

        alert(datastr);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.script.php",
            data: datastr,
            success: function(html){
            $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#response").html(html);
            //setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
            }
            ,error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                $("#response").html('there was an error');
                            console.log('error thrown');
                            console.log(errorThrown); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can see the page in operation at http://www.stillframe.com.au/test.php and you can see the form without the page media at at the same link above but test2.php

I've also added the script without any other jQuery to the same url but test3.php which posts directly to the contact PHP script to confirm there are no errors in that script.

SOLVED: Removed the base href tag from the head and the script now works fine.

Comment: have u tried making your URL contain the data, and remove the 'data' line?
 url: 'contact.script.php?name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text,

Comment: Im not getting an error on test2.php it seems to be working?

Comment: Thanks James. On test 2 did you receive a 'Thanks for getting in touch' response or did you get 'There was an error' response?

Comment: This is really confusing me. I have changed the URL params to the one Johnny updated above. Same response. However it seems some people have been trying the form as I am getting emails sent to me, thus indicating the form is working as intended. When I try it FF and Chrome it doesnt work, throws the error and no email is sent.

Comment: Just to clarify test3.php will work as it bypasses the Ajax request and posts straight to the PHP script.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using field by field, use the FORM ID `<form id="myform">` and serialize it. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#sendmail").click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.script.php",
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(output) {
                $("#form-div").css("float", "left");
                $("#form-div").html("<p>Thank you for contacting Stillframe Photography.</p><p>Please wait for just a few moments while your enquiry is being sent.</p>");
                $("#form-div").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#response").html(output);
                $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
                //setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                $("#response").html('there was an error');
                            console.log('error thrown');
                            console.log(errorThrown); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This script generated numerous exception errors.

Answer (score -4):

It is better to use ajax with raw javascript because of the following reasons.

1. Code is very simple and short.
2. You will never end with any error.
3. You target is just to send variables from javascript to php in correct rest will be taken care of , lemme add a sample code below for you.

   ```
   function insert(){
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
       xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(xmlhttp.readyState == '4' && xmlhttp.status == '200')
       {
           document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;    
       }
   }

   name = document.getElementById('insert').value;

   parameters = 'insert=' + name;

   xmlhttp.open('POST', 'day3.include.php', true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   xmlhttp.send(parameters);
   ```

   }

In parameters pass all of your variables accordingly and create a div#msg to display the reply from php.

If you have any confusion ask me back on http://www.thetutlage.com

Comment: -1.  You will "NEVER" end with an error?  Really?  I'm sure I could figure out a way.  Your answer is pure preference, and it doesn't solve the OP's issue in the manner that HE programmed.